# EventListener not filtering - instead, showing ALL events

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, binance, ethers.js

```
var mudralock_abi = ['event OnTokenLock (uint256 lockId, address tokenAddress, address owner, uint256 amount, uint256 unlockTime)']
var mudralock_contract = new ethers.Contract("0xae7e6cabad8d80f0b4e1c4dde2a5db7201ef1252", mudralock_abi, myProvider["bsc"])
 const mudralock_filter = mudralock_contract.filters.OnTokenLock
mudralock_contract.on(mudralock_filter, async(result) => {  //code here })
```

For some reason the listener is firing off on EVERY event, not just "OnTokenLock". What is wrong?